# Python gnupg: "No Pinentry" error during key deletion

Tags: python-3.x, gnupg

I'm building a python3 application, that generates a GPG key, asks for a passphrase and de/encrypts files. I want, that the correct passphrase input is required every start of the application.

Currently it seems, that the gpg-agent still holds the passphrase after the application is closed. A restart of the application does not require the correct passphrase to decrypt the data.

So I've had the idea to export the keys (public and private) into an ASCII armored file, import it on the start and deleting the keys again from the keyring, when the application closes. When I try to delete the keys (private key first, as described here at the [documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/python-gnupg/)) and show the stderr of the resulting object, it shows me a "No Pinentry" Error.

I've written a short test program:

```
import gnupg
gpg = gnupg.GPG(gnupghome="testhome")
input_data=gpg.gen_key_input(name_email="vault@mydomain.com", key_type="DSA", subkey_type="RSA",passphrase="Test")
key = gpg.gen_key(input_data)
if not gpg.list_keys():
    print(key.stderr)
    exit()
status=gpg.delete_keys(gpg.list_keys(True)[0]['fingerprint'],secret=True, passphrase="Test")
print(status.stderr)
```

The last print statement shows this:

```
gpg: Hinweis: Keine voreingestellte Optionendatei '...testhome/gpg.conf' vorhanden
gpg: enabled debug flags: ipc
gpg: DBG: chan_5 <- OK Pleased to meet you, process 2103
gpg: DBG: connection to agent established
gpg: DBG: chan_5 -> RESET
gpg: DBG: chan_5 <- OK
gpg: DBG: chan_5 -> OPTION ttytype=xterm-256color
gpg: DBG: chan_5 <- OK
gpg: DBG: chan_5 -> OPTION display=:0
gpg: DBG: chan_5 <- OK
gpg: DBG: chan_5 -> OPTION xauthority=/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority
gpg: DBG: chan_5 <- OK
gpg: DBG: chan_5 -> OPTION putenv=XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus
gpg: DBG: chan_5 <- OK
gpg: DBG: chan_5 -> OPTION putenv=GTK_IM_MODULE=ibus
gpg: DBG: chan_5 <- OK
gpg: DBG: chan_5 -> OPTION putenv=DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
gpg: DBG: chan_5 <- OK
gpg: DBG: chan_5 -> OPTION putenv=QT_IM_MODULE=ibus
gpg: DBG: chan_5 <- OK
gpg: DBG: chan_5 -> GETINFO version
gpg: DBG: chan_5 <- D 2.2.4
gpg: DBG: chan_5 <- OK
gpg: DBG: chan_5 -> OPTION allow-pinentry-notify
gpg: DBG: chan_5 <- OK
gpg: DBG: chan_5 -> OPTION agent-awareness=2.1.0
gpg: DBG: chan_5 <- OK
gpg: DBG: chan_5 -> OPTION pinentry-mode=loopback
gpg: DBG: chan_5 <- OK
gpg: DBG: chan_5 -> HAVEKEY A50FB634D9E33FEE1D9B8861A563F4C53BC20CD1
gpg: DBG: chan_5 <- OK
gpg: DBG: chan_5 -> HAVEKEY A50FB634D9E33FEE1D9B8861A563F4C53BC20CD1
gpg: DBG: chan_5 <- OK
[GNUPG:] KEY_CONSIDERED 12E6713D592E3FA210EE05E9558B0205D1894962 0
gpg: DBG: chan_5 -> SETKEYDESC MÃ¶chten+Sie+den+ausgewÃ¤hlten+geheimen+OpenPGP+SchlÃ¼ssel+wirklich+dauerhaft+entfernen?+(j/N)%0A%22Autogenerated+Key+<vault@mydomain.com>%22%0A2048-Bit+DSA+SchlÃ¼ssel,+ID+558B0205D1894962,%0Aerzeugt+2019-07-03.%0A?
gpg: DBG: chan_5 <- OK
gpg: DBG: chan_5 -> DELETE_KEY A50FB634D9E33FEE1D9B8861A563F4C53BC20CD1
gpg: DBG: chan_5 <- ERR 67108949 Kein Pinentry <GPG Agent>
gpg: Fehler beim LÃ¶schen des privaten SchlÃ¼ssels: Kein Pinentry
gpg: DBG: chan_5 -> HAVEKEY 489F5816348DA3C7D2540D5748CD0AC1E4ACA459
gpg: DBG: chan_5 <- OK
gpg: DBG: chan_5 -> SETKEYDESC MÃ¶chten+Sie+den+ausgewÃ¤hlten+geheimen+OpenPGP+UnterschlÃ¼ssel+wirklich+dauerhaft+entfernen?+(j/N)%0A%22Autogenerated+Key+<vault@mydomain.com>%22%0A3072-Bit+RSA+SchlÃ¼ssel,+ID+42CA4781026C931E,%0Aerzeugt+2019-07-03+(HauptschlÃ¼ssel-ID+558B0205D1894962).%0A?
gpg: DBG: chan_5 <- OK
gpg: DBG: chan_5 -> DELETE_KEY 489F5816348DA3C7D2540D5748CD0AC1E4ACA459
gpg: DBG: chan_5 <- ERR 67108949 Kein Pinentry <GPG Agent>
gpg: Fehler beim LÃ¶schen des privaten UnterschlÃ¼ssels: Kein Pinentry
gpg: 12E6713D592E3FA210EE05E9558B0205D1894962: delete key failed: Kein Pinentry
gpg: secmem usage: 224/65536 bytes in 1 blocks
```

Since the error message contains german, I will try to translate these passages correctly:

```
gpg: Notice: No preset options file '...testhome/gpg.conf' found
gpg: enabled debug flags: ipc
gpg: DBG: chan_5 <- OK Pleased to meet you, process 2103
gpg: DBG: connection to agent established
gpg: DBG: chan_5 -> RESET
gpg: DBG: chan_5 <- OK
gpg: DBG: chan_5 -> OPTION ttytype=xterm-256color
gpg: DBG: chan_5 <- OK
gpg: DBG: chan_5 -> OPTION display=:0
gpg: DBG: chan_5 <- OK
gpg: DBG: chan_5 -> OPTION xauthority=/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority
gpg: DBG: chan_5 <- OK
gpg: DBG: chan_5 -> OPTION putenv=XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus
gpg: DBG: chan_5 <- OK
gpg: DBG: chan_5 -> OPTION putenv=GTK_IM_MODULE=ibus
gpg: DBG: chan_5 <- OK
gpg: DBG: chan_5 -> OPTION putenv=DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
gpg: DBG: chan_5 <- OK
gpg: DBG: chan_5 -> OPTION putenv=QT_IM_MODULE=ibus
gpg: DBG: chan_5 <- OK
gpg: DBG: chan_5 -> GETINFO version
gpg: DBG: chan_5 <- D 2.2.4
gpg: DBG: chan_5 <- OK
gpg: DBG: chan_5 -> OPTION allow-pinentry-notify
gpg: DBG: chan_5 <- OK
gpg: DBG: chan_5 -> OPTION agent-awareness=2.1.0
gpg: DBG: chan_5 <- OK
gpg: DBG: chan_5 -> OPTION pinentry-mode=loopback
gpg: DBG: chan_5 <- OK
gpg: DBG: chan_5 -> HAVEKEY A50FB634D9E33FEE1D9B8861A563F4C53BC20CD1
gpg: DBG: chan_5 <- OK
gpg: DBG: chan_5 -> HAVEKEY A50FB634D9E33FEE1D9B8861A563F4C53BC20CD1
gpg: DBG: chan_5 <- OK
[GNUPG:] KEY_CONSIDERED 12E6713D592E3FA210EE05E9558B0205D1894962 0
gpg: DBG: chan_5 -> SETKEYDESC 
Do you really want to delete the private OpenPGP subkey permanently? (y/N) Autogenerated+Key+<vault@mydomain.com>%22%0A2048-Bit+DSA+Key,+ID+558B0205D1894962,generated+2019-07-03.%0A?
gpg: DBG: chan_5 <- OK
gpg: DBG: chan_5 -> DELETE_KEY A50FB634D9E33FEE1D9B8861A563F4C53BC20CD1
gpg: DBG: chan_5 <- ERR 67108949 No Pinentry <GPG Agent>
gpg: Error during deletion of the private key: No Pinentry
gpg: DBG: chan_5 -> HAVEKEY 489F5816348DA3C7D2540D5748CD0AC1E4ACA459
gpg: DBG: chan_5 <- OK
gpg: DBG: chan_5 -> SETKEYDESC 
Do you really want to delete the private OpenPGP subkey permanently? (y/N) Autogenerated+Key+<vault@mydomain.com>%22%0A3072-Bit+RSA+Key,+ID+42CA4781026C931E,generated+2019-07-03+(Main Key-ID+558B0205D1894962).%0A?
gpg: DBG: chan_5 <- OK
gpg: DBG: chan_5 -> DELETE_KEY 489F5816348DA3C7D2540D5748CD0AC1E4ACA459
gpg: DBG: chan_5 <- ERR 67108949 No Pinentry <GPG Agent>
gpg: Error during deletion of the private subkey: No Pinentry
gpg: 12E6713D592E3FA210EE05E9558B0205D1894962: delete key failed: No Pinentry
gpg: secmem usage: 224/65536 bytes in 1 blocks
```

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04, python3.6.7, gnupg version 2.2.4 (as shown by gpg.version)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I now solved the issue.

When deleting the secret key, GPG tries to invoke pinentry, which will display a graphical confirmation dialog. As here GPG is invoked from a python script, it seems, that it does not know of any graphical desktop, where it could show this dialog, so it gives out an error (at least that is my interpretation of the problem).

This can be solved, by telling the GPG object, to provide the option `--yes` to all gpg commands. This will deactivate the confirmation dialog. So I just changed the definition line of the GPG object to

```
gpg = gnupg.GPG(gnupghome="testhome",options=['--yes'])
```

Now the deletion of the secret key is executed without an error.